# symfony2 multiple file upload error with dropzone.js

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload, dropzone.js, multiple-file-upload

I'm using dropzone.js on my symfony 2.3 project to let the user upload many pictures at once. But i get an strange error :

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on a non-object
```

I thought it was my controller, so i created a simple page, with a simple file upload to try uploading :

```
<form method="post" action="/project/web/app_dev.php/interne/global/galerie/add-photos/30" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="file" multiple name="photos" />
<input type="submit" value="guacamole" />
</form>
```

It uploads one picture with success, but when i select two or three pictures, only one is uploaded. I believe there's a mistake somewhere but I cant find it. Here is mya
 controller :

```
public function addPhotosAction($id) {

    $request = $this->get('request');
    $files = $request->files;
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $album = $em->getRepository('ExterneGalerieBundle:Album');
    $album = $album->find($id);

    if(is_null($files->get('photos'))) {

        return new JsonResponse('Nothing to upload');
        exit;
    }

    foreach ($files as $uploadedFile) {

        $path = __DIR__ . '/../../../../web/photos/' . date("Y") . '/';

        $name = $id . '__' . time() . '__'  . getClientOriginalName() .  '.jpg';

        $file = $uploadedFile->move($path, $name);

    }

    return new Response('');
}
```

I believe `dropzone.js` doesn't upload a file? And why only one file at a time ? Thanks in advance,

Comment: You should try digging into the Symfony profiler. Now there's only one possible bug as it seems: you're checking `$files->get('photos')`, but then you process `$files` variable. Aren't your files in the `$files->get('photos')` var?

Comment: well, thanks a lot buddy, i let you put it as a solution, that's why it was only uploading one file... Thanks buddy !